# how to run ".desktop" file from bash script

Tags: bash, .desktop

I have a script (using rofi and find) that returns various files.  When it finds a "something.desktop" file I want to be able to launch it from the bash script.  Similar questions said "use gtk-launch", but it must be depreciated as I can't find it with synaptic.

Is there a more modern way to do this (besides finding the line "Exec=..." and dealing with that)?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 2):

- To run a `.desktop` file anywhere on your disk, you can install the tool **`dex`**. Run the desktop file with `dex /some/path/foo.desktop`.
- To run a `.desktop` file that is installed in one of the dedicated locations on your system (where it is being picked up from your menu), you can use **`gtk-launch`** (part of the `libgtk-3-bin` package), for example `gtk-launch foo`. You can specify the extension, but there is no need. Put your custom `.desktop` files in `.local/share/applications` in your home folder to be able to run them this way. If you are a system administrator, place them in `/usr/local/share/applications`so they are available for all users.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install [`gtk-launch` command](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=gtk-launch) with

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-bin
```

and then run the desktop file with it:

```
gtk-launch something.desktop
```