# How to set keyboard shortcut to open desktop shortcut?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, .desktop, shortcuts

For example, I have desktop shortcut for `Telegram` with config file `/usr/share/applications/telegram.desktop` that has the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Telegram Desktop
Exec=/opt/telegram/Telegram -- %u
Comment=Official desktop version of Telegram messaging app
Icon=/opt/telegram/telegram.svg
StartupWMClass=Telegram
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;
MimeType=application/x-xdg-protocol-tg;x-scheme-handler/tg;
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22
```

This desktop shortcut was added to `Favorites` and visible in Ubuntu `Dash` panel on desktop.

Is it possible to define keyboard shortcut for this desktop shortcut?

I suppose that this should be configured in `Settings` -> `Keyboard Shortcuts` -> `Custom Shortcuts`. But specification there either the desktop file or the command in this file:

- `/usr/share/applications/telegram.desktop`
- `/opt/telegram/Telegram -- %u`
- `/opt/telegram/Telegram`

is not working.

In `Windows` keyboard shortcut can be specified just inside properties of the desktop shortcut. If it possible how to configure such behavior in `Ubuntu`?

Comment: maybe take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332731/how-to-run-desktop-file-from-bash-script)

Comment: @Andra Great, with specification command as `gtk-launch telegram.desktop` the keyboard shortcut is working. You can post this as answer. Thanks!

Comment: it's better you write the answer yourself - you solved your problem

Comment: @Andra Only with your help. So it would be more honestly if you post this an answer and I will accept it. But if you still want me to do this I will.

Comment: I also checked `dex` tool. With it keyboad shortcut also works but full path to the desktop file should be specified. Example: `dex /usr/share/applications/telegram.desktop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to specify command as:

```
gtk-launch telegram.desktop
```

Or to install `dex`:

```
sudo apt install dex
```

and to specify command as:

```
dex /usr/share/applications/telegram.desktop
```

Source: [how to run ".desktop" file from bash script](https://askubuntu.com/a/1332883/1548713)

Checked on Ubuntu 20.04.